# How to design Twitter interface Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

In my android app i want to design a layout exactly like twitter layout with a **Image and Text View**.

See the following screenshot

[image]

Please help me with this. How can i design this layout ?

**Update:**

Forget about background images and top bar. I am requiring 6 images and textviews. In the below image twobirds with Tweets(167), Lists, Mentions, Retweets etc.,

Comment: dude,, what a textView and image u mean ?  for example - where two birds and text (Tweets(167)) or in bottom of the screen ? where  text = #nowplaying ?

Comment: @Peter: Sory to mention. Forget about background image and all. I want those 6 images and textviews. Thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is called a Dashboard pattern.

You can find implementation of ActionBar and Dashboard patterns in [sources of the Google IO app](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/). ActionBar in the file [actionbar.xml](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/res/layout/actionbar.xml) (and [HomeActivity.java](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/HomeActivity.java), [ActivityHelper.java](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/util/ActivityHelper.java)), Dashboard in the file [fragment_dashboard.xml](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/res/layout/fragment_dashboard.xml) (and [DashBoard.java](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/DashboardFragment.java)).

Answer (score 2):

What you want is fairly simple, tho I am sure there are more fancy way's of doing this then i'm
about to show you.

For my application I used 4 ImageButtons, but the principle is the same for 4 or 6 buttons.

This is my XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_layout" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="45dip"
    android:background="@drawable/actionbar_background"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tekst"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="App name"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/button_layout" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_below="@id/actionbar_layout">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_schedule"
        android:src="@drawable/schedule_icon"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_schedule"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:text="Rooster"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_schedule"
        android:gravity="center" 
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_locations"
        android:src="@drawable/locations_icon"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"        
        android:layout_below="@id/text_schedule"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_locations"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:text="Links"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_locations"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_rss"
        android:src="@drawable/rss_icon"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_schedule"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_rss"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:text="RSS"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text_schedule"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_rss"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_settings"
        android:src="@drawable/settings_icon"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text_locations"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_schedule"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_settings"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:text="Instellingen"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text_locations"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_settings"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:gravity="center"
        />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/twitter_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/button_layout">

   <Gallery android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/gallery"           
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">    
   </Gallery>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I pasted the whole file, so you can see how I implemented my actionbar.
But what you need is the second RelativeLayout tag.

You align your buttons/textviews by using "android:layout_toRightOf" and "android:layout_below" attributes.

Your first button is simple, the second one (the one to its right) you align with "android:layout_toRightOf="@id/first_button"

A third button (below the first button) can be aligned using "android:layout_below="@id/first_button"

The same goes for textviews, just use layout_toRightOf and layout_below to align them. The attributes only apply to the RelativeLayout.

Hope this will help you out a bit.

Answer (score 0):

im sure , it's can be created like this :

```
image and textView mustBe on  layout - so :
    //start "a" code
    LinearLayout oneObject ;
    oneObject= new LinearLayout(this);
    //need set to vertical mode  
    oneObject.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    //it's our one object . image+text
    next : TextView text = new TextView(this);
    text.setText("tweets"); // or get from array 
    ///image it's can be what you want - button, layout, textView(-____-) 
    // just need set on background new image . iget button - for normal clicking ;//
    ImageButton image = new ImageButton(this);
    image.setImageResource(r.drawable.blabla)
    oneObject.addView(image);
    oneObject.addView(text);
//also u need create 2 columns and add to this columns our object

//for size of oneObject - use LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(curWidth/2,curHeight/6); curWidth and curHeight - its my resolution of screen.
//end "a" code
```

for creating 6 objects  u must rung it in cycle : 
all code = "a"; so

```
for(int i = 0;i<6;i++)
{
 a/// where a all our code
}
```

Hope it's help you.. also i can put more code where need some fixings